# How to perform minimum amount in sql query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My question is: which film has taken the least takings at a performance? Include film name and cinema name in the result.

My `performance` table has the following columns:

```
performanceid, cinemano, screenno, filmno, performancedate, takings
```

`moviename` is in the `movie` table and `cinemaname` is in the `cinema` table

Comment: And what **datatype** are those columns? You should provide the proper, SQL "CREATE TABLE" scripts for **ALL** tables involved for us to be able to help you!

Comment: @Petru Maika when you want to leave a comment, click on the *add a comment*. Don't click on *edit*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the limited info you posted:

```
SELECT 
    p.performance_id, 
    p.cinema_no, c.cinema_name, 
    p.screen_no, 
    p.film_no, f.film_name, 
    p.performance_date, 
    p.takings 
FROM performance p
INNER JOIN film f ON f.film_no = p.film_no
INNER JOIN cinema c ON c.cinema_no = p.cinema_no 
WHERE p.takings = (SELECT MIN(takings) FROM performance)
```